# Document Management with hyperlinks

Tags: document-management, hyperlink

Hoping someone can recommend a system or piece of software (preferably OSX or cloud based) that allows for easy document management. However, I am looking for something very specific.

Essentially, I am trying to create a standard operating manual for my business. Within this document, I imagine that I will want to reference other documents. For example, if I had a statement within my document that reads:

"Once a new client has returned a signed contract, the Project Manager should send the New Project Questionnaire (PQ_992) and request the new client fills it out in entirety."

I would like the PQ_992 document reference to link to the correct document (in this case the New Project Questionnaire) within the system.

Not even sure if software like this exists, but I am hoping someone has seen this before. I have scoured the internet for something like this, but ultimately have just found document storage software. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco can do this, at the condition that your standard operating manual is written as a Wiki page (don't worry, Wiki does not mean the document is editable by everyone, it means that it can be edited online).

First put your PQ_992 document (for instance a Word or LibreOffice file) in the document repository.

Then create the standard operating manual, as a Wiki page.

In this Wiki page, select the PQ_992 word and click "Insert Document Link":

[image]

This will open a dialog that lets you select the document you want to link to:

[image: select doc]

When you have selected it, save, and you now have your beautiful standard operating manual containing a link to the right document:

[image]

Alfresco is usually installed on a server so that all employees can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a dms but it solves your issue with operating manual of any size: Help & Manual from ec-software. We have our operating manual in it with such hyperlinks and publish relevant parts for each job title. Has version control, reasonable priced (free would be better but everyone needs to make a living ). I know two customers of us whom have also switched to it for their operating manuals because they have many operating units, each with similar but different administrative and control requirements.